# SQL: How can I generate a time series from timestamp data and calculate cumulative sums across different event types?

Tags: sql, time-series, cumulative-sum

Building a timeseries with cumulative sums based on singe grouped events

To begin I need to highlight I am quite new to SQL and the current state was achieved with the help of stack overflow.

I have a table containing events of different kinds as they occur. I would like to transform this data into a time series filling the time gaps between the events and cumulating the numbers across the different kind of events.

So it is all about creating a timeseries from single events and calculate the running/cumulative sum across groups of events

Here the example of source data:

Source:

```
event_timestamp    type  value
01.01.2023 10:00   1     10
03.01.2023 10:00   2     10
05.01.2023 10:00   2     10
07.01.2023 10:00   1     10
```

Desired outcome:

```
event_timestamp    type value cumulative_sum
01.01.2023 10:00   1    10    10
02.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
03.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
03.01.2023 10:00   2    10    10
04.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
04.01.2023 10:00   2    0     10
05.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
05.01.2023 10:00   2    10    20
06.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
06.01.2023 10:00   2    0     20
07.01.2023 10:00   1    10    20
07.01.2023 10:00   2    0     20
```

I got to a point, where I can create this (limited to a single event type):

```
time               type value cumulative_sum
01.01.2023 10:00   1    10    10
02.01.2023 10:00   1    0     10
03.01.2023 10:00   1    10    20
04.01.2023 10:00   1    0     20
05.01.2023 10:00   1    0     20
06.01.2023 10:00   1    0     20
07.01.2023 10:00   1    0     20
```

with the following sql statement (postgresql):

```
SELECT  
generate_series AS timestamp,
-- hard coded event type below
COALESCE(events.type, 1) AS type,
COALESCE(events.value, 0) AS value,
COALESCE(SUM(td.value) OVER (ORDER BY generate_series), 0) AS cumulative_sum  
FROM  
generate_series('2023-01-01'::timestamp, '2023-01-07'::timestamp, '1 day') AS generate_series  
LEFT JOIN  
-- hard coded event type below
events ON generate_series = events.event_timestamp AND event.type = 1 
ORDER BY  
generate_series;
```

Now I am questioning if I should try to find the SQL statement doing all in a better way (no idea how) or if I should use a python script to just run this statement per event type and sequentally , insert the data into the table.

Questions summarized:

- Would it be advisable to do such a calculation with a combination of SQL and e.g. python?
- Would it be better to split the creation of the timeseries and the cumulative sum?
- If the pure SQL way is recommended, how can this done considering the groups

Comment: Just as an aside, I think your expected result is incorrect.  Type 1 accumulation shouldn't hit 20 until the last timestamp, if I understand your description properly.

Comment: Well I double checked and you are right - I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.  All you need is to create the series for each type.  A cross join can do that easily.

Check this out:

```sql
SELECT generate_series AS timestamp
     , etypes.type
     , COALESCE(events.value, 0) AS value
     , COALESCE(SUM(events.value) OVER (PARTITION BY etypes.type ORDER BY generate_series), 0) AS cumulative_sum
  FROM generate_series('2023-01-01'::timestamp, '2023-01-07'::timestamp, '1 day') AS generate_series
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM events) AS etypes
  LEFT JOIN events ON generate_series = events.event_timestamp AND events.type = etypes.type
 ORDER BY generate_series, etypes.type
;
```

With no data in the given range, the result is this:

| timestamp | type | value | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

[Test case (with a little data added)](https://dbfiddle.uk/jBg0D-wg)

You could also create the series with different range for each type, based on the start and end for that type.

Here's an example of that:

```sql
SELECT generate_series AS timestamp
     , etypes.type
     , COALESCE(events.value, 0) AS value
     , COALESCE(SUM(events.value) OVER (PARTITION BY etypes.type ORDER BY generate_series), 0) AS cumulative_sum
  FROM (SELECT type
             , MIN(event_timestamp) AS mints
             , MAX(event_timestamp) AS maxts
          FROM events
         GROUP BY type
       ) AS etypes
  JOIN LATERAL (SELECT generate_series(mints, maxts, '1 day') AS generate_series) AS gs ON 1 = 1
  LEFT JOIN events ON generate_series = events.event_timestamp AND events.type = etypes.type
 ORDER BY generate_series, etypes.type
;
```

Result with your data:

| timestamp | type | value | cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | 2 | 10 | 20 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 2023-01-07 00:00:00 | 1 | 10 | 20 |

Comment: Thabk you very much

Comment: This solution helps me a lot. I have an additional question: I will store desired outcome in a table (let's call it event_history) to work on this. I was wondering if I can do the calculation incremental by replacing the MIN() statement with the increment day. 
To maintain the overall sum:

Would it be better to add the last result per type each time?

or 

Would it be smarter to Insert temporary placeholder entries per type at the beginning of the list?

Comment: It's hard to tell what would be best.  If I really had to do this, I might just extend the current result, by starting with the last calculated sum per type from the most recent result.  This can be done easily in the above solution.  The min/max range which drives calculation is easily replaced.